# How can I see a custom claim that I've added to my user's access token from the User's Identity?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token, claims-based-identity, jwt

I need to access a custom claim that I'm adding to the User after Authentication

In my auth server I'm adding custom claims to the response as follows

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("MyNewClaim", "lol"));
        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
```

On my calling client I can see that the raw token, which I inspect in `OnTokenResponseReceived`, has the claim when I decode it

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived += ctxt =>
    {
        ctxt.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken // <-- has raw token that contains claim
```

The calling client has a middleware component that attempts to read the claims from the User's identity:

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.User.Identity;
        
        var hasNewClaim = claimsIdentity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "MyNewClaim"); // always false
```

The problem I have is that the claim is never there.

**Question:**
What do I need to do to access the new claim in my User's Identity?

Comment: You may have to add a ClaimAction to map your custom claim: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/

Comment: That looks like it would work, but unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: What about adding `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` to ` ConfigureServices` in your `Startup`?

Comment: Still didn't do the trick. I'm going to post what eventually worked later when I get it all reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to retrieve the supplementary data from the token service's /UserInfo endpoint.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // stuff

    options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived += context =>
    {
        // get UserInfo data from the context
        var userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenIdConnectUserInfo>(context.User.RootElement.ToString());

        // do stuff with the newly acquired info.

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    // go home and tell your kids you love them
});
```